Azure Data Factory stored procedure activity times out
I have created a stored procedure activity. When I attempt to refresh the stored procedure name, it times out. However, it was working fine about 30 minutes ago.

Can anyone think of any reasons for this to suddenly happen?

Can you show the error message


If you are not getting stored procedure name in dropdown, you can select Enter manually checkbox and give the stored procedure name manually in the text box.



Even after giving the stored procedure name manually, while executing the stored procedure activity, if you get the error, then the error could be stored procedure is deleted or access to stored procedure is revoked.

You can give the below code to give the access to stored procedure.
GRANT  EXECUTE  ON  <OBJECT::SCHEMA.storedprocedure> TO <ROLE/USER>;

